# Android - In Realm DB how to query for records where a RealmList<RealmString> is not empty?

Tags: android, realm

How to query for records where a field `RealmList<RealmString>` is not empty? Is it possible or do I have to loop through all the records?

```
public class Type extends RealmObject {

    private boolean isSearchable;

    private RealmList<RealmString> types = new RealmList<>();

}
```

How to query Realm DB to get the records which don't have empty types ?

Comment: Can you give an example please? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

```
List<Type> recordsWithNoEmptyTypes = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
    .where(Type.class)
    .isNotEmpty("types")
    .findAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an `isEmpty()` operator that can be used to query for empty lists: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmQuery.html#isEmpty-java.lang.String-